# Failed sonar migration because table already exists

Tags: sonarqube

I am trying to upgrade Sonarqube from 3.7.4 to 4.5.4

I've updated all the plugins and the new application starts as expected.

I then go to the /setup URL where I am prompted to start the DB migration. This fails with the following error:

```
ActiveRecord::JDBCError: Table 'rule_tags' already exists:
```

I've backed up my v3.7.4 DB, and when I restore it, I can see that it already contains a table called rule_tags, which has zero records. With the restored backup and older plugins in place, v3.7.4 starts up again just fine.

The migration code is is attempting to create this table without checking if it already exists.

Anyone know why this could be happening? I suspect it has something to do with some earlier failed migration.

Comment: Do you have the full logs please ?

Comment: By the way the table rule_tags is created in version 4.2. So if it's still present when restoring your mysql backup, that means that you restored only data but not structure. Double check your command-line to restore mysql schema.

Comment: Hi, that sounds about right. I'll re-create the DB and do another restore to get the schema back in shape. Put your response in an answer and if it works I'll give you the reps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The table rule_tags is created in version 4.2. So if it's still present when restoring your mysql backup, that means that you restored only data but not structure. Double check your command-line to restore mysql schema.

Comment: Thanks. I dropped the existing sonar DB, re-created an empty one, and then restored again, which gave me a clean DB on which to perform the data migration.